# Using log4net to log in Api from class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, log4net

I have a webapi for which I am trying to debug.

I use a generic repository structure so all my entity framework calls are made in a separate class library.

So my web Api post end point effectively just calls service.insert(entity). Where the generic insert is in the separate class library.

Logging is currently setup and working in the api.  Now I want to log the insert Sql generated by entity framework in the parent applications text log file (as something strange is going on in the live environment)

How would I go about doing this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to do this depends on what version of Entity Frameework you are using. In EF6 and later it is simple:

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    // log is a log4net logger
    context.Database.Log = message => log.Debug(message);

    // insert the entity
}
```

See [this blog series](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/) for more information - [part 3](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/14/ef6-sql-logging-part-3-interception-building-blocks/) shows an example of logging to NLog with a command interceptor - and [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) for options relating to earlier versions of EF.